# How to calculate benefit of some specific product type in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, here are my tables:

**Sales**

| id | product_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4536 |
| 2 | 4674 |

**Products**

| product_code | product_name | price | real_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4536 | Red bull energy drink 300 ml | 3,68 | 2,88 |
| 4674 | Mac coffee 25 gr | 2,59 | 2,10 |

*I need to calculate how much benefit did I get from the products which have "Red Bull" in its name. Benefit is equal to price-real_price.*

Expected output:

| product_name | benefit |
| --- | --- |
| Red bull energy drink 300 ml | 4536,4 |

Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT products.product_code,(price-real_price) as profit
FROM products
INNER JOIN sales
ON products.product_code = sales.product_code
outer apply (select count(*) 
            from sales as benefit
where product_name like '%red bull';
```

But it does not give me the output I want to get.

Comment: In your desired result why benefit=4536,4? it should be 0.8

Comment: It's just an example.

Comment: One point, you could use the LIKE to search for values that contain 'red bull' like this 'red bull%' and you'll get better performance than what you currently have. Also, wild card, then 'red bull' won't return a value for the existing string 'Red bull energy drink 300 ml' since it doesn't match that pattern.

Comment: bring more clarity to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table Sales (
   id int, 
   product_code int)

create table Products(
   product_code int,
   product_name char(100),
   price smallmoney,
   real_price smallmoney)

insert into Sales values   
   (1, 4536),
   (2, 4674),
   (3, 4536) -- to have multiple sales for Red Bull
   
insert into Products values
   (4536, 'Red bull energy drink 300 ml', 3.68, 2.88),
   (4674, 'Mac coffee 25 gr', 2.59, 2.10)
   
select 
   p.product_name, sum(p.price - p.real_price) benefit
from Sales s join Products p on s.product_code = p.product_code
group by p.product_name
```

| product_name | benefit |
| --- | --- |
| Mac coffee 25 gr | 0.4900 |
| Red bull energy drink 300 ml | 1.6000 |

Answer (score 0):

As you say that each line is one quantity sold the following query will do the job.
I suggest that it would be better to have a quantity column in the sales table.

```
select
  p.product_code,
  p.product_name,
  count(s.product_code) as quantity_sold,
  sum( (p.price-p.real_price)*count(s.product_code) as total_profit
from products p 
join sales s on s.product_code = p.product_code
where p.product_name like '%red bull'
group by
  p.product_code,
  p.product_name;
```

Comment: Quantity is considered as repetition of product_code.

Comment: That's a suprising data structure. Will your create 10 lines for a customer who buys 10 cans of Red Bull?